# Multi Layer Solution - The type 'Customer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the following layout for my solution.

- Data Layer
- Entities Layer (POCO's to create code-first db)
- Services Layer (Web API)
- Web Layer (MVC Layer for presentation)

I have created models in the Web API Layer that mimic the entities in the Entities layer so I can more easily reference properties. I have those called Models. I would like to have the API layer do the data work in case I want to upgrade the Web Layer later or go a different direction. I have used the VS 2019 Controller creation tool and I have referenced my Services Layer Model as the model and the Data Context from my Data Layer. I get the following error:

```
"Error  CS0012  The type 'Customer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'XX.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.XX.Services"
```

I can see why I get that, the Model in the Service layer (though matches property wise) does not match the namespace. How does one reference the Data Layer without using something like AutoMapper? It seems like I am missing something obvious, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Services layer is going to contain your logic and interact with your entities, and your MVC Controllers are largely anemic, passing through to the Services, it sounds like you want your Services to return Models (DTOs or ViewModels) which decouple the data returned from your entities.

To do this, Services will need a reference to your Entities because that is what your data layer is. Ideally the data layer should be returning `IQueryable<TEntity>` as opposed to `IEnumerable<TEntity>` or even `TEntity` so that the services can refine queries for efficiency without bringing back more data than they need, or adding lots of complexity or a large number of similar single-purpose methods in the data layer.

I'm not sure what your aversion to Automapper is, but it is perfectly suited to handling the conversion and copying of data between Entity and ViewModel. You can certainly do it without Automapper using Linq's `Select` method.

For instance, to get a list of OrderModels out of your service:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderModel> GetOrdersForCustomer(int customerId, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var orders = OrderRepository.GetByCustomerId(customerId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
        .Select(x => new OrderModel
        {
             OrderId = x.OrderId,
             OrderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
             CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt,
             // ... et al, 
             OrderItems = x.OrderItems.Select( oi => new OrderItemModel
             {
                 OrderItemId = oi.OrderItemId,
                 ProductId = oi.Product.ProductId,
                 ProductName = oi.Product.Name,
                 Quantity = oi.Quantity,
                 UnitPrice = oi.Product.Price,
                 // ...
             }).ToList()
        }).Skip(pageNumber*pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
     return orders;
}
```

Clumsy, but flexible and gets the job done. With Automapper mapping configured:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderModel> GetOrdersForCustomer(int customerId, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var orders = OrderRepository.GetByCustomerId(customerId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
        .ProjectTo<OrderModel>()
        .Skip(pageNumber*pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
     return orders;
}
```

The key to something like this working efficiently in terms of performance and memory use is that `OrderRepository.GetCustomerById(int)` returns `IQueryable<Order>` not `IEnumerable<Order>` This allows the `Select`/`ProjectTo` and `Skip` & `Take` to be compiled down to the SQL which returns just the columns needed to populate your models.

ViewModels/DTOs do *not* need to match their Entity counterparts 1:1. You only need to include fields you know the consumers will use. This helps protect your schema but also can streamline the amount of data that gets sent over the wire, boosting performance and reducing server memory usage. You can define as many view models as you need for an entity, and use inheritance to extend them if desired.

When going the other way, such as performing an insert or update, Automapper can help simplify data transitions, and even cover rules to ensure that data that should not be changed, never gets changed. You can load entity graphs in your service similar to above, but using `Include` to pre-fetch related data that might be updated and selecting the particular entity(ies) to update. With Automapper you can handle both insert scenarios and updates:

Inserts:

```
var newOrder = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderViewModel);
_context.Orders.Add(newOrder);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Updates:

```
var existingOrder = _context.Orders.Single(x => x.OrderId = orderViewModel.OrderId);
_mapper.Map(orderViewModel, existingOrder);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

... and for singular entities you're pretty much done.  A little more work may be needed for updating related entities with the Order.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, this is really what I was looking for. I am not totally averse to using AutoMapper and based on your explanation I likely will. I was thinking maybe I was just over complicating everything and there was not a need for AutoMapper. I really like the idea of almost completely decoupling away from my services layer so that I can manage this while my developers (I am a lead) can just update the UI as new data features become available.